# How to install the application on my smart watch from Tizen Studio

Tags: android, sensors, tizen

I am quite new in smart watch apps development. My final objective is to collect a raw data from sensors of smart watch and send it to Android mobile app.

As a first step I wanted to start with creating a simple application on my Gear S3 and downloaded the last version (v2.4) of Tizen Studio on my Windows PC. I was going through tutorials on YouTube and learning materials from developer.tizen.org.

However, I found that there is either a few information available on the internet or the old content (directions are for old version of Tizen Studio) event in the main web site of Tizen.

So, please help to understand the main concepts of smart watch apps development, how should I properly install the new version Tizen Studio and run the application on my Gear S3 (NOT Emulator). And if you have any useful materials, please share with me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the following site for most of your questions.

- [Samsung Gear Development Site](https://developer.samsung.com/gear)
- [Youtube webinars on Gear development from Samsung Developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL7PfK8Mp1rLFc7D7JB-GOAdjxeswtsED-)
- [Samsung Gear development community](https://developer.samsung.com/forum/?topCtgy=03)
- [Tizen development community](https://developer.tizen.org/forums)

Most of the information in the videos should apply.